# How to block specific user to visit specific pages in Django

Tags: django

My Django project have some 10 apps.

I am using default User.

Then there is Role model, something like this

```
class Role(models.Model):
    user_type = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    is_manager = models.BooleanField()
    is_employee = models.BooleanField()
```

As I told I have 10 apps. Each app has its urls.py

User with is_manager = True can visit all first 8 apps pages(pages those are in urls.py). But they should not be able to visit other 2 app pages.

Similarly is_employee = True, User can only visit last 2 app pages and they cannot visit first 8 app pages.

I don't know how to achieve such situation.

Comment: How is your front-end, are you using Django views, or are you using an independent front end platform, such as Angular or React?

Comment: normal Django-views. No angular no react just html, css and js @HuLu ViCa

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`dispatch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.dispatch) method of class based views.

In each app, you can have a base class which checks the permissions. If the user doesn't have permission, you can throw a 403, or redirect to a common page and show some relevant message.

The following is the Base class. All apps will have a separate base class inheriting from this class and just implementing the `check_user` method.

```
class AuthenticationBaseClass(object):
    error_message = "You are not authorized to view this app"
    redirect_path = reverse_lazy('app:url')  # replace with suitable url name from urls.py

    def user_check_failed(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        messages.error(request, self.error_message)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.redirect_path)

    def check_user(self, user):
        return True 

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.check_user(request.user, request):
            return self.user_check_failed(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return super(AuthenticationBaseClass, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Now, in app1/views.py. Implement the base class and then inherit all the view classes from this class.

```
class UserCheck(AuthenticationBaseClass):
    def check_user(self, user):
        if user.role.is_manager:
            return True
        return False

class View1(UserCheck, TemplateView):
   ...

class View2(UserCheckMixin, TemplateView):
   ...
```

Similarly for other apps, you can do the same, and change the permissions needed to access the pages for that particular app.

Alternatively, you can create custom decorators for different permissions and decorate all urls in the same app with the same decorator.

```
def manager_login_required(function):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kw):
        user=request.user  
        if not user.role.is_manager:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/unauthorized/')  # or raise 403
        else:
            return function(request, *args, **kw)
    return wrapper


# in urls.py for an app:

url(r'^view/$', manager_login_required(MyView.as_view()), name='view'),
```